# Вывод в шестнадцатиричной системе счисления в окно интерпретации

Tags: visual-studio

Вопрос, думаю, достаточно банальный. Скорее всего, решается где-нибудь в настройках одной галочкой. Но я уже второй день эту галочку найти не могу.

Среда Visual Stusio 2017.

В ранних версиях значок "шестнадцатиричный вывод" был в панели отладки: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А сейчас я в упор этой кнопки не вижу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И получаю вывод в консоль в 10-ричном формате. Гугл на мой вопрос отсылает к форматированию строк в духе `cout << hex << число`. Короче, не понимает он меня. Прошу помощи

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28025

Comment: @XelaNimed, не не, не VSCode. Visual Studio

Comment: Скорее всего нужно будет использовать плагин...